# KeyCloak Client Behind reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, oauth-2.0, reverse-proxy, keycloak, nginx-location

I have the following issue.
Both, my KeyCloak and the Client are behind a reverse Proxy.

My reverse Proxy Configuration for the Client:

```
    server_name my.domain.here.com;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9254;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```

When the Client now tries to sign in with oAuth, KeyCloak has the following error:
Invalid parameter: redirect_uri

Because the valid redirect URI I specified is: my.domain.here.com/*
And the requestion redirect URI is: http://localhost/9254/*

Is there a way, to pass the server-name to the KeyCloak?

Comment: can you specify `/*` redirect uri and check if it works?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. The issue was not KeyCloak, the issue was the client. The client has responded as localhost. I just configured him now the right way.